# Apache errors - *** glibc detected *** Backtrace - perl

Tags: apache-2.2, httpd, perl, logging, glibc

I have been getting these errors in my apache logs on my server - it only happened once a day or every two days.
Any idea what could be causing this? I dont even have an idea of where to start?

```
*** glibc detected *** /usr/sbin/httpd.worker: double free or corruption (!prev): 0xb10515f0 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
...
```

See the full output of the error and backtrace here:
http://pastebin.com/emUCQVzg

Here is another instance of the same kind of error:
http://pastebin.com/Gg4HC1CU

Comment: Posts are limited to 30K characters.

Comment: So How should I go about adding the complete dump??

Comment: Pastebin? but I doubt that it'll be much use to us this is most likely either a bug for the Apache group to solve or a hardware fault.

Answer (score 2):

Your Apache or one of it's modules has crashed. This could be a hardware problem or it could be a bug in Apache or one of it's  modules. Diagnosing it could be quite difficult.

- Update your Apache and it's modules to the latest version for your OS/Distro.
- Put it all on different hardware
- File a bug report with the Apache group.